# Sharing code between iOS & Android projects

Tags: android, web-services, ios, mobile

I've been hired to develop a mobile framework for a webservice created by my employer. Ideally management would like to have some reusable components that can be shared across mobile platforms (initially iOS & Android, probably Windows Phone 7 at some later point).

I've been wondering how feasible this is. One of the requirements is a native interface, so we would use Cocoa Touch on iOS & whatever (Java-based) toolset is used to create a native UI for Android. The application will interact with webservices, mainly the ones that we've been creating internally. The webservices have been developed in .NET.

As far as reusable components go, I guess we could use some C++ code to make webservice calls and perhaps even more of the backend of an application, yet I wonder if this would be a good approach. Apple's Foundation Framework has some excellent capabilities build-in to access webservices, not to mention other open-source libraries, e.g. ASIHttpRequest, SBJSON, etc... I guess the same would be true for Android (though I have no real Android experience for now). Also, when looking at projects done by companies like Google, Twitter & Facebook, each of these companies offers native libraries built for the major mobile OS platforms. If the big companies take this approach, it seems logical for us to follow suit.

Perhaps we should focus more on a general architecture that we should offer across platforms instead of an implementation that can be shared.

Would anyone advise us to make use of C/C++ to develop such a framework (shared library) for the mobile site of our webservices? If so, why?

Comment: Bit confused, which bit do you want to be shared? a Web service will have a standard, say SOAP. Clients can then implement calls to that web service, you could look at AXIS2 for java (for android), not sure about iOS, but there is probably something similar.

Comment: It's about the code that runs on the mobile clients, preferably most of the code "behind" the user interface of the mobile device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which WS protocol you use it may be more or less hard to do, but anyway I see little advantage in doing that in C/C++ for a mobile platform.
If you were using SOAP, I'd never consider C/C++, even for a desktop app. I already used SOAP libraries for C++ and they are a lot harder to use than their Java/.net counterparts, and the way they are implemented (mapping SOAP objects to C structs) is very prone to crashes if the format changes. Not to mention that you have to recompile your client when the WSDL changes.

As I understood in your case you plan to use REST. I never found a good REST library for C/C++, but recently I did a desktop project in which I implemented a C++ REST client using simply WinHTTP (in Windows) and libCURL (in Linux). Of course, they provide just the HTTP part, so I had to add cppdom for XML parsing. If you use JSON, there are many good libs like jsoncpp, libjson.

I'd say to you that even in a desktop environment it was harder to do than would be in .net or java, and was only done this way because it was part of a larger application already written in C/C++.

Anyway, you'll have more work and not much advantage since all those modern mobile platforms provide rich libraries that do the same thing, and probably the user of your API will develop in the platform's main language, so you'll have the double extra work of implementing the WS access code AND the binding code. As I assume all (or at least most) of your logic is in your server, not the client, there's not much common code between the platforms to justify using C/C++.

Comment: Yes, we're considering using RESTful webservices with the JSON format. I've found some C++ libraries that support this, though it's often unclear how well these libraries are supported on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Usually Linux-based libs with not much dependencies are not difficult to port to them, since their base is similar, but you'll have to test. I already compiled & used some libs in iOS without problems. Never had a similar experience with Android, thought.

Comment: I guess I'll try to create a demo app for both iPhone and Android that calls a webservice and makes use of a shared lib for the webservice calls, see how it all works out. I understand that Android makes use of the (non-standard) boost library, I can imagine that could give some issues.

Comment: Also be careful about C++ libs that do the entire RESTful thing, they may give away flexibility. For my app I found better to use http+xml libs only due to the more fine-grained control I had.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what level of customized code you want to have.  I worked at a game company previously, and we made two games for both iPhone and Android, and at least 90% of the codebase was shared between the two platforms in c++ code.  Sometimes it is significantly easier to implement elements with specialized third-party libraries, like for Facebook and the like, but maintaining that code means continually doing it for both platforms.  That was one of the reasons why we even implemented our own UI objects in c++ for our games.  Because even though the initial setup would have been easier to do with Interface Builder and Android's XMLs, the maintenance and tweaking necessary ended up being significantly less because we went with a shared codebase.

In short, I would highly recommend writing any shared customized code in C/C++, and things that are significantly easier in their native codebases (java for android, or obj-c for iphone) and you don't expect to change much, to keep separate.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about this aspect, for games it seems really effective, but I can't help but wonder if this is an effective approach for information applications. Thanks for your answer though, gives me some points to think about.

Comment: Yeah, games and information applications definitely have different points to consider when coding.  The real point I was trying to help with, was that you need to consider not only implementation, but maintenance as well.